# In Haskell, does mutability always have to be reflected in type system?

Tags: haskell, immutability, ghc, mutability, type-theory

I'm new to Haskell, so please forgive if this question is dumb.

Imagine that we have two data structures bound to the names *x* and *y*.

*x* is mutable.

*y* is not.

As a matter or principle, does *x* necessarily have a different type than *y*?

Comment: There are no mutable variables in Haskell. At best, we have (immutable) references to mutable data, such as `IORef Int`, `STRef s Int`, and several others. Even when using references, to read or write the referred values we typically need to be in some monadic context, and that must be exposed in the types. Concretely, a function `IORef Int -> String` can not use the referred `Int` at all (not ever read it). A function `IORef Int -> IO String` can instead access the referred `Int` -- note how this is exposed by the `IO` in the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

In Haskell, all *variables* are technically immutable.  Unlike in, say, JavaScript, once you've defined a new variable in Haskell and bound it to an initial value:

```
let x = expression1 in body1
```

that's its value forever.  Everywhere that `x` is used in `body1`, its value is guaranteed to be the (fixed) value of `expression1`.  (Well, technically, you can define a brand new immutable variable `x` with the same name in `body1` and then some of the `x`s in body might refer to that new variable, but that's a whole different matter.)

Haskell does have mutable *data structures*.  We use them by creating a new mutable structure and binding that to an immutable variable:

```
do ...
   xref <- newIORef (15 :: Int) 
   ...
```

Here, the value of `xref` *itself* is not the integer 15.  Rather, `xref` is assigned an immutable, undisplayable value that identifies a "container" whose contents are currently 15.  To use this container, we need to explicitly pull values out of it, which we can assign to immutable variables:

```
  value_of_x_right_now <- readIORef xref
```

and explicitly put values into it:

```
  writeIORef xref (value_of_x_right_now + 15)
```

There's obviously much more that can be said about these values, and the way in which they generally need to be accessed via monadic operations in `IO` or another monad.

But, even setting that aside, it should be clear that the integer `15` and a "container whose contents are initialized to the integer `15`" are objects with necessarily different types.  In this case, the types are `Int` and `IORef Int` respectively.

So, the mutability of data structures will necessarily be reflected at the type level, simply by virtue of the fact that mutability in Haskell is implemented via these sorts of "containers", and the type of a value is not the same as the type of a container containing that value.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to point out that an `IORef` is very much like a mutable array with exactly one element.